# How to add padding on to a byte array?

Tags: java, encryption, padding

I have this **40 bit** key  in a `byteArray` of size **8**, and I want to add 0 padding to it until it becomes **56 bit**.

```
byte[] aKey = new byte [8];  // How I instantiated my byte array
```

Any ideas how?

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right, could you please confirm: You have a byte array of size 8 which stores a 40 bit key (that is 5 bytes) and you want to left-pad (or prepend) the unset bits (or 0's) until 56th bit. Is my understanding right?

Comment: yea you are right i believe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An 8 byte array is of 64 bits. If you initialize the array as

```
byte[] aKey = new byte [8]
```

all bytes are initialized with 0's. If you set the first 40 bits, that is 5 bytes, then your other 3 bytes, i.e, from 41 to 64 bits are still set to 0. So, you have by default from 41st bit to 56th bit set to 0 and you don't have to reset them.

However, if your array is already initialized with some values and you want to clear the bits from 41 to 56, there are a few ways to do that.

**First:**
you can just set `aKey[5] = 0` and `aKey[6] = 0` This will set the 6th bye and the 7th byte, which make up from 41st to 56th bit, to 0

**Second:** If you are dealing with bits, you can also use BitSet. However, in your case, I see first approach much easier, especially, if you are pre Java 7, some of the below methods do not exist and you have to write [your own methods](http://www.exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/java.util/Bits2Array.html) to convert from byte array to bit set and vice-versa.

```
byte[] b = new byte[8];
BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(b);
bitSet.clear(41, 56); //This will clear 41st to 56th Bit
b = bitSet.toByteArray();
```

Note: `BitSet.valueOf(byte[])` and `BitSet.toByteArray()` exists only from Java 7.

Answer (score 4):

Use System.arraycopy() to insert two bytes (56-40 = 16 bit) at the start of your array.

```
static final int PADDING_SIZE = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] aKey = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; // your array of size 8
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aKey));
    byte[] newKey = new byte[8];
    System.arraycopy(aKey, 0, newKey, PADDING_SIZE, aKey.length - PADDING_SIZE); // right shift
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newKey));
}
```

Comment: I would use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));` in the method `printArray(byte[] array)` to print out an array

Comment: Sure, good remark. I'm using basic java arrays really rare :)

Answer (score 1):

Guava's  `com.google.common.primitives.Bytes.ensureCapacity`:

```
aKey = Bytes.ensureCapacity(aKey , 56/8, 0);
```

or since JDK6 using Java native tools:

```
aKey = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(aKey , 56/8);
```